# Play Sound and alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to play a small beep in my web application and then launch an alert message.

I therefore do:

```
if(_none_valid) {
    $.playSound('/static/wav/beep_error.wav').delay(300);
    alert('ERROR: Not found.');
}
```

What happens is that the .wav file is played AFTER the user has dismissed the alert.

I have tried to add `delay(300)` as shown.

Why is this happening? How should be fixed?

I am using this [library](https://github.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are adding a delay of `300`ms for `$.playSound`. You need to add a delay or **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)** for `alert()`:

```
if(_none_valid) {
    $.playSound('/static/wav/beep_error.wav');
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('ERROR: Not found.');
    }, 300);
}
```